Value not changing between tables
Here's code for a timer:
local copyTable = require("Helpers.copyTable")

local timer = {}

timer.max = 0
timer.time = 0

function timer:add(dt)
    timer.time = timer.time + dt
end

function timer:reset()
    timer.time = 0
end

return copyTable(timer)

The copy table function returns a new table containing all the values of the one copied.
Here's some basic code that uses it:
ovenTime = require("timer")

ovenTime.add(.5)

print(ovenTime.time)

This gives me the output of 0.
I was expecting it to output .5 since time gets .5 added onto it.
Thanks in advance!

Most importantly, if you declared the method add() with a semicolon, so you should invoke it: ovenTime:add (.5), not ovenTime.add (.5).
With other small improvements:
timer.lua:
local copyTable = require 'Helpers.copyTable'

local timer = { max = 0, time = 0 }

function timer:add (dt)
    self.time = self.time + dt
end

function timer:reset ()
    self.time = 0
end

-- serialisable "decorator":
local function serialisable (tbl)
    local meta = getmetatable (tbl) or {}
    meta.__tostring = function (tbl)
        return tostring (tbl.time)
    end
    return setmetatable (tbl, meta)
end

return serialisable (copyTable (timer))

and the calling program:
ovenTime = require 'timer'

ovenTime:add (.5) -- note ':' instead of '.'.

print (ovenTime) -- it will output '0.5', not 'table: 0x...'

And some further simplifications of timer.lua:
-- serialisable 'decorator':
local function serialisable (tbl)
    local meta = getmetatable (tbl) or {}
    meta.__tostring = function (tbl)
        return tostring (tbl.time)
    end
    return setmetatable (tbl, meta)
end

return serialisable {
    time = 0,
    max = 0,
    add = function (self, dt)
        self.time = self.time + dt
    end,
    reset = function (self)
        self.time = 0
    end
}

And finally, a solution that allows several independent timers, since that is what you seem to want, since you deep copied tables:
timer.lua:
-- serialisable 'decorator':
local function serialisable (tbl)
    local meta = getmetatable (tbl) or {}
    meta.__tostring = function (tbl)
        return tostring (tbl.time)
    end
    return setmetatable (tbl, meta)
end

return function ()
    return serialisable {
        time = 0,
        max = 0,
        add = function (self, dt)
            self.time = self.time + dt
        end,
        reset = function (self)
            self.time = 0
        end
    }
end

and its caller:
local timer = require 'timer'
local ovenTime = timer ()
ovenTime:add (.5)
print (ovenTime)

